# How to implement Server side pagination using angular 2

Tags: angular, pagination, server-side

I am new in angular 2 so please help me.

I want to implement **angular 2** and **angular 4** to get data from database and apply **server side pagination** on it.

Answer (score 5):

There is a NPM package that handles this for you [ngx-pagination](https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination)

There are documents there that outline exactly how to get it working. You can see a live demo [here](http://michaelbromley.github.io/ngx-pagination/#/server-paging), which includes a server side paging example with code

Comment: which packages I have to installed?

Comment: All the information is in the links, it's just `npm install ngx-pagination --save`. See the links in my answer for details

Comment: C:\Users\mkumar2\Downloads\ngx-pagination-master\docs>npm install ngx-pagination
 --save
C:\Users\mkumar2\Downloads\ngx-pagination-master\docs>npm start
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mkumar2\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-12-04T12_22_5
4_250Z-debug.log